# Java: Program will stop in a certain condition then press any key to continue... it will continue to loop

Tags: java

Problem is I will print all the characters in the keyboard, however everytime it counts 10 the program will stop then press any key to continue.. the sequence will continue.. so far this is what i've done.

```
public class AsciiDisplay
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i<=255; i++)
            System.out.printf("%d\t%c\n",i,i);
    }
}
```

Comment: `I will print all the characters in the keyboard` I'm curious how you can do this

Comment: Yes, please add more of your code or details

Comment: If a key is pressed : continue I understand, but how do you want to define "not continue" ? just waiting for a key pressed ? or like "if in the 10sec you didn't press a key it stops ?

Comment: Don't know exactly why this happens, but consider that codes below 32 (decimal) are assigned to control characters rather than printable ones: these may have different effects according to where the program is running in.

Comment: To elaborate on rrobby86's comment, look at an ASCII table value 0-31. Many of those are not printable characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String a[]){
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i<=255; i++){
            if(count == 10){
                System.out.println("Press \"ENTER\" to continue...");
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                scanner.nextLine();
                count = 0;
            }else{
                System.out.printf("%d\t%c\n",i,i);
                count++;
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: The loop would never stop. you'd probably want an if(count % 10 == 0) loop instead no?

Comment: it will stop after 255 iteration. counter variables are different.

Comment: True but you don't even need an if else, you can just use an if (i +1 % 10 == 0) to use for the scanner input and add that to his current code before the print statement

Comment: Ah... I see. The asker's question is ambiguous. I interpreted _Problem is..., however everytime it counts 10 the program will stop_ as this is what was happening and they wanted to know why. You interpreted it as that is what the asker wanted to do.

Comment: Yup that also would work

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider :- thanks mate

Comment: Sorry for my ambiguous question for the reason I want to simplify it. I guess I didnt get it correctly, Anyway, thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Logic:- 
Maintain a counter, increment it every time you print a character, after every 10 increments, it will stop for the user to provide the input, as scanner methods are blocking.

*count%10 ==0 means, the number is completely divisible by 10.*

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        {
            int count=0;
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            try{
            for (int i = 0; i<=255; i++){
                System.out.printf("%d\t%c\n",i,i);
                 count++;
                 if((count%10)==0){
                        System.out.println("Click to continue...");

                        scanner.nextLine();
                }
               } 
              }
        finally{
            scanner.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Though above code is not printing characters by taking input from keyboard.

Comment: Sorry for my bad grammar, hahahaha. @rkosegi

Comment: ll just stop it the count is 10 then press anykey to continue this will happen until all the characters is printed. @MatMateuszW90

Comment: There was a small typo, now check.

Comment: Thanks for that @Amir Bhati. Is there any workaround if im not use the try and finally?

Comment: You can remove them, code will work fine, but in case something goes wrong in your code, your scanner will not close, it'll remain open. Waste of resource. Check this link:- https://www.quora.com/Why-do-we-need-to-close-the-scanner-class-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, is good solution, beacuse I understood, You want press any key, after 10 numbers was printed starts from 0. Right?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

  private static final Scanner SCANNER = new Scanner(System.in);

  public static void main(String a[]) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 255; i++) {
        count++;
        if (count % 10 == 0) {
            System.out.printf("%d\t%c\n", i, i);
            System.out.println("Press \"ENTER\" to continue...");
            SCANNER.nextLine();
            count = 0;
        } else {
            System.out.printf("%d\t%c\n", i, i);

        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You nailed it @MateuszW90.